# How to mount a USB drive that doesn't have a standard name

Tags: usb, mount

I have a USB stick that I'm trying to access, and, when I enter

```
sudo lshw
```

I find the stick with the following information

```
*-usb:2
               description: Mass storage device
               product: MobileMate Reader
               vendor: SanDisk
               physical id: 4
               bus info: usb@1:4
               logical name: scsi4
               version: 94.07
               serial: 070925400664
               capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
               configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

I tried to copy only the information that seemed relevant, there was a lot of other information displayed too.  In any case, the instructions I've seen elsewhere all note that `logical name:` typically is of the form `/dev/sdb1` or something.  Obviously mine does not, and there is no file or folder named `scsi4` on my computer that I can find.

I've tried running

```
sudo mkdir /media/usbstick

mount scsi4 /media/usbstick
```

but I get the error message that `scsi4` doesn't exist.

Effectively all I want to do is access the USB stick as a folder, put a Linux disk image on it, and be able to take that to another computer to wipe it clean and install Linux on it.

Comment: And there's no `/dev/scsi4` ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Nope

Comment: Have you tried mounting the drive using disks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using a [Usb to MicroSD converter](https://www.sandisk.com/home/memory-cards/memory-card-readers/mobile-mate). It represents itself as a "usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host".

Any device connected to that host (i.e. any MicroSD card) would have a name like /dev/sdX.

Then any partition on that MicroSD card would have a name like /dev/sdX1, /dev/sdX2, etc.

If that is the case even if you copy stuff to that MicroSD card then you might not be able to boot from it. Just don't let me stop you from trying :-)

Be **extremely** careful about which device name you are using. It is quite likely that you main hard disk has a name like /dev/sda and if you decide to re-partition and re-format that **you will lose all your data**!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, I just grabbed something that looked like a USB stick from a bucket of electronics and assumed it was a USB stick--wrong assumption, it seems.  Thanks!